# MVVM Data Binding not updating

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a small WPF application and I'm beginning to learn the MVVM Data Binding pattern. I have an empty textBox and I have bound it to "FirstName" however when I run my code it's not updating. I have an ObservableObject class which inherits from the `INotifyPropertyChanged` class to check if the property has been updated. When I run the code the property does take the correct value however the UI never updates.

My code is as follows

MainWindow.xaml

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FirstName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" Margin="20,20,0,20" Width="132"></TextBox>
```

Main Windows.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

Person.cs

```
class Person:ObservableObject
{
    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }

        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
class MainViewModel:ObservableObject
{
    List<Person> pList = new List<Person>();
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        pList = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person() {FirstName="Craig"}
        };
        Init();
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        var li = pList.FirstOrDefault();

    }

}
```

OnservableObject.cs

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    #region Constructor

    protected ObservableObject()
    {
    }

    #endregion Constructor

    #region DisplayName

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the user-friendly name of this object.
    /// Child classes can set this property to a new value,
    /// or override it to determine the value on-demand.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string DisplayName { get; protected set; }

    #endregion DisplayName

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    [field: NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpresssion)
    {
        var propertyName = PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(propertyExpresssion);
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    #region Debugging Aides

    /// <summary>
    /// Warns the developer if this object does not have
    /// a public property with the specified name. This
    /// method does not exist in a Release build.
    /// </summary>
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        // Verify that the property name matches a real,
        // public, instance property on this object.
        if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
        {
            string msg = "Invalid property name: " + propertyName;

            if (this.ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName)
                throw new Exception(msg);
            else
                Debug.Fail(msg);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns whether an exception is thrown, or if a Debug.Fail() is used
    /// when an invalid property name is passed to the VerifyPropertyName method.
    /// The default value is false, but subclasses used by unit tests might
    /// override this property's getter to return true.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual bool ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName { get; private set; }

    #endregion Debugging Aides

    #region IDisposable Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this object is being removed from the application
    /// and will be subject to garbage collection.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.OnDispose();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Child classes can override this method to perform
    /// clean-up logic, such as removing event handlers.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void OnDispose()
    {
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Useful for ensuring that ViewModel objects are properly garbage collected.
    /// </summary>
    ~ObservableObject()
    {
        string msg = string.Format("{0} ({1}) ({2}) Finalized", this.GetType().Name, this.DisplayName, this.GetHashCode());
        Debug.WriteLine(msg);
    }



    #endregion IDisposable Members
}
```

PropertySupport.cs

```
public static class PropertySupport
{
    public static String ExtractPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpresssion)
    {
        if (propertyExpresssion == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyExpresssion");
        }

        var memberExpression = propertyExpresssion.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The expression is not a member access expression.", "propertyExpresssion");
        }

        var property = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (property == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The member access expression does not access a property.", "propertyExpresssion");
        }

        var getMethod = property.GetGetMethod(true);
        if (getMethod.IsStatic)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The referenced property is a static property.", "propertyExpresssion");
        }

        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, the `FirstName` is not updated in the UI side? "Craig" never shows? It's a little bit confused...

Comment: By the way; `FirstName` is contained in `Person`, who belongs to the `pList`. In the UI, you bind directly to `FirstName`; not to a selected person or something like that. I'm pretty sure there is an error in your binding path!

Comment: I bet there are explanatory binding errors in the debug output window while you are debugging the application

Answer (score 1):

You should make a property CurrentPerson, or something like this, in your MainViewModel. CurrentPerson should be e.g. the first entry of your pList. Then you can bind to CurrentPerson.FirstName.

Answer (score 1):

The `MainViewModel` has no property called `FirstName`. In fact, it has no property at all.

If you define `pList` as a *public property*:

```
class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public List<Person> pList { get; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        pList = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person() {FirstName="Craig"}
        };
    }
}
```

...you can bind to the first `Person` object in the `List<Person>` like this:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding pList[0].FirstName}" />
```

Alternatively, you could add a `Person` property that returns the value of `pList.FirstOrDefault()` to the `MainViewModel` class and bind to this one in your XAML.

But you can only bind to public properties. You cannot bind to fields.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind the Model's property directly to the UI. 
Think what you are going to bind to the TextBox. You are having a list of Person, from which you may bind selected person's FirstName property to the TextBox. In that sense, create a SelectedPerson property in ViewModel and bind the SelectedPerson.FirstName to the TextBox which would work.

Add the below property  to your viewmodel

```
private Person _selectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return _selectedPerson; }

        set
        {
            _selectedPerson= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");
        }
    }
```

And try to bind as follows in XAML

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.FirstName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" Margin="20,20,0,20" Width="132"></TextBox>
```